# Почему метод выбрасывает ошибку?

Tags: java

Решаю задачу на степике.
Gри вводе решения платформа выдает ошибку:
Неожиданное исключение: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1.
Не понимаю, почему так происходит?
Можете подсказать, что делаю не так?

Условие задачи:
Магазину нужно сохранять информацию о продажах для каждого сотрудника. Напишите метод Map getSalesMap(Reader reader) который принимает Reader содержащий строки вида:

Алексей 3000
Дмитрий 9000
Антон 3000
Алексей 7000
Антон 8000.
Метод должен получить все строки из Readera и заполнить и вернуть карту где ключом будет имя сотрудника, а значением сумма всех его продаж.

```
public class Sales {
    public static Map<String, Long> getSalesMap(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        int fromReader = reader.read();
        String line = String.valueOf(fromReader);
        while(line != null) {
            String name = line.trim().split(" ")[0];
            Long salary = Long.parseLong(line.trim().split(" ")[1]);
            if (map.containsKey(name)) {
                map.put(name, map.get(name) + salary);
            } else {
                map.put(name, salary);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Похоже что проблема в этой строке Long salary = Long.parseLong(line.trim().split(" ")[1]);

Comment: Во-первых, зачем сплитить одну и ту же строку дважды.

@PerfectVoyage так trim() только крайние пробелы убирает, это не должно влиять.

Comment: @Nyuhnyash Удалил чтобы не вводить в заблуждение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неправильно работаете с Reader. Метод [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read--) согласно документации вычитывает только первый символ. Используйте, например, [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), чтобы считывать данные построчно:

```java
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
String line = br.readLine();
```

В вашем случае будет удобно воспользоваться классом [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) для считывания данных, например:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
String name = scanner.next();
long salary = scanner.nextLong();
```

Comment: Спасибо вам!)))